# Minimize Standard Deviation in Google OR-tools

Tags: c#, optimization, or-tools

I'm currently writing a program using Google OR-Tools to divide a number of students into a variable number of groups.
Each student can choose a "friend" (another student) with whom he/she would like to be in the same group.

The constraints for the problem are:

- Each student must be assigned to one group
- Students who want to be in the same group, must be assigned to the same group

I'm trying to maximize the "fairness" of the distribution by minimizing the standard deviation of the number of students in each group.

This is my code so far:

```cs
Student student = new Student("123", "Sam", null);
Student student2 = new Student("234", "Jos", student);
Student student3 = new Student("345", "Jef", null);
Student student4 = new Student("456", "Jane", student3);

List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
{
    student, student2, student3, student4
};

const int GROUPS = 2;

CpModel model = new CpModel();

//create array
BoolVar[,] assignments = new BoolVar[students.Count,GROUPS];

for(int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < GROUPS; j++)
    {
        assignments[i, j] = model.NewBoolVar($"assingments_{i}_{j}");
    }
}

//each student should be assigned to one group
for(int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
{
    IList<ILiteral> groupsForStudent = new List<ILiteral>();

    for(int j = 0; j < GROUPS; j++)
    {
        groupsForStudent.Add(assignments[i, j]);
    }

    model.AddExactlyOne(groupsForStudent);
}

//friends should be in the same group
for(int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
{
    Student first = students[i];

    if(first.Friend != null)
    {
        int otherIdx = students.IndexOf(first.Friend);


        for(int j = 0; j < GROUPS; j++)
        {
            model.AddAbsEquality(assignments[i, j], assignments[otherIdx, j]);
        }
    }
}
```

But now, I'm stuck on implementing the minimisation constraint.

Could someone provide me with some example code please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is usually easier to minimize the bandwidth:

```
min maxnum-minnum
maxnum >= x[i]
minnum <= x[i]
```

OR-tools also has some AddMaxEquality and AddMinEquality functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Could you provide a code snippet how I can achieve this using Google OR-tools please?

Comment: "Could someone provide me with some hints please?"